# What is better than fire and brimstone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, puzzles

One of the worst cards in the game is [Fire and Brimstone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fire%20and%20Brimstone): for 5 mana, you can deal 4 damage to yourself and target player. Except that this would clearly have been too powerful, so it’s restricted to only a target player who has attacked this turn.

But I’m having a hard time finding a card which is strictly better. [Pierce Strider](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pierce%20Strider) is close, but that’s only 3 life rather than 4.

And yes, strictly better means no other mana costs besides white. I’d be ok with {W}{W}{W}{W}{W} if needed.

Comment: Even given the damage difference, Pierce Strider is not strictly better than Fire and Brimstone as it is sorcery speed.

Comment: A card that is identical to Fire and Brimstone except that it costs {W}{W}{W}{W}{W} would generally be considered strictly worse, because the mana cost is more restrictive.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I get the feeling Charles is looking to add burn to a mono white commander deck, so amount of colored symbols isn't particularly going to matter there. Amount of colored symbols isn't exactly considered strictly worse since it can situationally better in something like mono devotion.

Comment: The only coherent way to evaluate strictly better/strictly worse is to consider the general case in isolation, and not special cases that might change the evaluation. Losing life is strictly worse than not losing life, even though Death's Shadow exists. A lower mana cost is strictly better than a higher mana cost, even though [mtg:Torrent of Fire] exists. Generic mana costs are strictly better than specific mana costs, even though the devotion mechanic exists.

Comment: @Andrew Treat it as a puzzle problem, not a deckbuilding problem.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Exactly. I'm willing to flex on colored mana cost (up to {W}{W}{W}{W}{W} rather than just {3}{W}{W}) but otherwise I'd like to follow precisely that definition.

Comment: Whether you use your definition or the more standard definition, Andrew's answer is correct: there is no card that is strictly better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Knight Paladin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knight%20Paladin), from Warhammer 40,000 Commander is probably as close as you're going to get.

Knight Paladin can only be cast at sorcery speed, rather than instant speed, but in all other respects it is equal to or better than Fire and Brimstone.

Both cost 5 mana
Knight Paladin is colorless rather than requiring white mana
Knight Paladin damages every opponent, not just one who attacked you this turn
Knight Paladin doesn't damage yourself
Knight Paladin comes with a spiffy 6/6 trample crew-1 vehicle once you're done dealing damage.

Comment: Amazing, you found one!

Answer (score 2):

There really are no strictly better versions of "Fire and Brimstone" using the definition of strictly better as (with at least being an improvement):

- More powerful or equal effect
- Faster or equal speed
- Lower or equal mana cost (including less colors and colored pips)

The closest card to following these rules is [Chalice of Life](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chalice%20of%20Life), the back half of the transforming artifact, Chalice of Death, taps to cause target player to lose 5 life, (loss of life being considered slightly better than damage as it's harder to prevent), but needing you to have gained significant life and needing to be on the field as a sorcery speed artifact makes it slower.

White isn't the color for direct damage or life loss, that's the job done by Red and Black in the color pie, so cards that deal direct damage that are playable in white are very narrow and niche.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "strictly better" does not include "must be mono white", [a trivial Scryfall search finds many options](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=oracle%3A%22deals+4+damage%22+type%3Ainstant+%28game%3Apaper%29):

- [Chandra's Fury](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chandra%27s%20Fury)
- [Consuming Sinkhole](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Consuming%20Sinkhole)
- [Flame Javelin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flame%20Javelin)
- [Flame Lash](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flame%20Lash)
- [Flames of the Blood Hand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flames%20of%20the%20Blood%20Hand)
- [Jeskai Charm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jeskai%20Charm)
- [Lightning Blast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Blast)
- [Prophetic Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prophetic%20Bolt)
- [Pulse of the Forge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pulse%20of%20the%20Forge)
- [Slaying Fire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Slaying%20Fire) (if cast with RRR)
- [Stoke the Flames](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stoke%20the%20Flames)
- [Unfriendly Fire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Unfriendly%20Fire)
- [Violent Eruption](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Violent%20Eruption)
- [Warleader's Helix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Warleader%27s%20Helix)

and then a ton of spells which deal *more* then 4 damage. If you do want mono white, that's sort of the point: white does not do direct damage.

Comment: Exactly: I’m looking for mono-white or colorless. (Yes, stepping out of that color gives lots of options, especially in red.)

Comment: Please edit that into the question, but again the answer is: white doesn't do that. You should find a different strategy for your deck.

Comment: A slightly easier variant: Suppose you have four white mana. What one card could cause your opponent to lose 4 or more life (through damage or direct loss of life) this turn? Creatures won’t help unless they’re unblockable and hasted.

Comment: Definitely more of a puzzle question rather than deckbuilding.

Comment: Comments are not for new questions - but you can ask that as an entirely new question (don't edit this one) if you want to. But still - don't expect to find a good one; MtG very deliberately defines the strengths and weaknesses of each colour.

Comment: "Strictly better" is a common term among magic players when analyzing cards, it means: The same or lower mana value, the same or fewer colors, the same or stronger effect (ie more damage, more power). Adding as color makes the card situationally better, but not strictly better

Comment: @Andrew is [Consuming Sinkhole](https://scryfall.com/card/ogw/94/consuming-sinkhole) strictly better than Fire and Brimstone? It has lower mana value (4), fewer colors (0. Yes it does. It says so on the card) and better effect. Things are not as simple as you would like to make out.

Comment: @PhilipKendall being the same fewer colors and costing the same or fewer colors are two very different things, it is not strictly better because the cost adds a color making it unplayable in many decks that could (but wouldn't) play Fire and Brimstone, my comment wasn't clear I should have said same or lower mana cost not mana value which does include color

Answer (score 1):

[This Scryfall search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=mv%3C%3D5+-m%3Awww+-m%3Au+-m%3Ab+-m%3Ar+-m%3Ag+%28t%3Ainstant+or+o%3Aflash%29+%28o%3A%2Fdeals.*%28X%7C%5B4-9%5D%7C%5Cd%5Cd%2B%7Cthat+much%29+damage%2F+or+o%3A%2Floses%3F+%28X%7C%5B4-9%5D%7C%5Cd%5Cd%2B%7Cthat+much%29+life%2F%29+o%3A%2F%28target%7Ceach%29+%28opponent%7Cplayer%29%7Cany+target%2F&unique=cards&as=checklist&order=edhrec&dir=asc) should reveal any strictly better cards. (with false positives)

They are all orthogonal (neither strictly better nor worse) to Fire and Brimstone, all involving preventing damage and dealing that much to a player.

```
mv<=5 # costs at most 5 mana
-m:www -m:u -m:b -m:r -m:g # does not include 3 white, or any other color
(t:instant or o:flash) # can be cast at instant speed
(
  o:/deals.*([4-9]|\d\d+|X|that much) damage/ # could deal at least 4 damage
  or
  o:/loses? ([4-9]|\d\d+|X|that much) life/ # or drain at least 4 life
)
o:/(target|each) (opponent|player)|any target/ # can affect an opponent
```

[Removing the requirement](https://scryfall.com/search?q=mv%3C%3D5+-m%3Awww+-m%3Au+-m%3Ab+-m%3Ar+-m%3Ag+%28t%3Ainstant+or+o%3Aflash%29+%28o%3A%2Fdeals.*%28X%7C%5Cd%2B%7Cthat+much%29+damage%2F+or+o%3A%2Floses%3F+%28X%7C%5Cd%2B%7Cthat+much%29+life%2F%29+o%3A%2F%28target%7Ceach%29+%28opponent%7Cplayer%29%7Cany+target%2F&unique=cards&as=checklist&order=edhrec&dir=asc) to deal at least 5 damage reveals [Springjaw Trap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Springjaw%20Trap). Which, for mere 5 generic mana can deal 3 damage at instant speed.

Comment: `id:w` probably isn't the right check here. That is a color identity search, not a color search. The point here is to search for cards with costs that are no more restrictive, and the most accurate way to do that is directly: `mana<=3ww or mana<=4w or mana<=5`

Comment: You are right, I'll update it. It won't include any hybrid costs, but I can't see any that match.

Comment: I didn't even think of hybrid costs. I don't think there's a concise way to include them in the search. But the color identity search wouldn't include them either.

Comment: There are also `X` costs to consider, for [Divine Deflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[divine+deflection]). Luckily that can easily be included

Comment: As powerful as Scryfall is, it would be great if it could recognise `1` < `R/W` < `W`

Comment: Negating each other color appears to work pretty well. It would include hybrids if any existed.